# How can I display the array on my listview in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am working on a reservation system

I need to display an array on a listview
I tried some codes however they dont work

Help me please

Thanks in advance;

This is OnCreateView part

```
public class Res extends Fragment {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_res, container, false);
        lv=view.findViewById(R.id.lview);

        getReservations();
        return view;
    }
```

and  this part is to receive data from google sheet whic has reservations and to display the reservations on my listview by using adapter.

```
private void getReservations() {

        loading =  ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Rezervasyonlar yukleniyor","Lutfen Bekleyiniz",false,true);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "HERE I HAVE THE URL ..WORKS ON GOOGLE APP SCRIPT BUT PROBLEM IS ABOUT MY CODE ",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        parseItems(response);
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        );
        int socketTimeOut = 50000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void parseItems(String jsonResponse) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("items");


            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                final String name = jo.getString("name");
                final String phone = jo.getString("phone");
                final String email = jo.getString("email");
                final String arriving = jo.getString("arriving");
                final String departure = jo.getString("departure");
                final String pax = jo.getString("pax");
                final String roomtype = jo.getString("roomtype");
                final String rate = jo.getString("rate");
                final String address = jo.getString("addres");
                final String company = jo.getString("company");
                final String agency = jo.getString("agency");
                final String ratecode= jo.getString("ratecode");

                HashMap<String, String> item  = new HashMap<>();
                item.put("name",name);
                item.put("email",email);
                item.put("phone",phone);
                item.put("arriving",arriving);
                item.put("departure",departure);
                item.put("company",company);
                item.put("pax",pax);
                item.put("roomtype",roomtype);
                item.put("rate",rate);
                item.put("address",address);
                item.put("agency",agency);
                item.put("ratecode",ratecode);

                list.add(item);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),list,R.layout.getres,
                //new String[]{"name","phone","email","arriving","departure","pax","roomtype","rate","address","company","agency"},new int[]{R.id.namev,R.id.phonev,R.id.emailv,R.id.checkv,R.id.depv,R.id.personv,R.id.roomtypev,R.id.ratev,R.id.adresv,R.id.companyv,R.id.agencyv});

        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);


        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white   ));
        loading.dismiss();

    }
```

Here I have XMLs that have textviews and listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    tools:context=".Res">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lview"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/background_light" />
</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/namev"
                android:layout_width="157dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emailv"
                android:layout_width="121dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="E-mail"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phonev"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Phone"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyv"
                android:layout_width="111dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Company"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adresv"
                android:layout_width="132dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/agencyv"
                android:layout_width="91dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Agency"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nationv"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Natinality"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idnov"
                android:layout_width="143dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="ID number"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/checkv"
                android:layout_width="111dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Arriving"
                android:inputType="date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/depv"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Departure"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/roomprv"
                android:layout_width="137dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Room Preference"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/roomtypev"
                android:layout_width="155dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Room Tye"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="113dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Pérson" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/personv"
                android:layout_width="134dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="0" />


        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ratecodev"
                android:layout_width="114dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Rate Code"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ratev"
                android:layout_width="151dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Rate"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />



        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:gravity="center">

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: could you please post your adapter code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see for sure that what exactly the issue is on your side. But I would suggest doing these things to confirm where the issue is.

## Make sure you are receiving something on the network call

You have this function inside your volley request.

```
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                parseItems(response);
            }
```

Did you make sure that response contains a valid JSON string that has your items?. So first try printing this response in the LOG and see if you are getting something from the request or not.

If you are getting something in your response, and still it is not working. Then comment the screenshot or the response string here. Also if you can reveal your URL where you are sending the request to fetch the data then it would be easy for me to check why it is not working in your case.

**Additional you should do this.  This is not the cause of your problem but you should use it this way.** This line of your code snippet

```
 lv=view.findViewById(R.id.lview); 
 getReservations();
```

Override the function onViewCreated() and put these two lines inside this function. But the actual problem is not here

Comment: Thanks for answering... you ve helped much.... problem is "item.put("ratecode") because there is no rate code to receive from the URL(My script) what a silly mistake.... but now there is other problem that progressdialog is on my screen and still says 'loading please wait,.receiving reservations' though I have already received

Comment: Because you forget to call hide function on progress dialog. So just call `loading.dismiss()` inside onResponse function and you should also call it inside onErrorResponse(). 
Please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: vote ? like this"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: You need to accept my answer, and you can do it because you asked the question. You cannot upvote because you have less reputation.